# Trimming the file path in a CSV up to a certain path/file name stored in a variable

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that stores the full paths of the files in a specific directory along with some other information. I have exported the CSV file. Now, the paths are actually being combined together to comprise of the full path. Let me give an example below:

```
$root= C:\Users\home\
$web = facebook website\domain
$app = facebook android\latest
```

These paths are then joined together with either `Join-Path` or `$fbweb = $root + $web` to make up the full path: `C:\Users\home\facebook website\domain`

Now the above mentioned path will have other files, subfolders etc in it but that's the gist of how the paths are structured. I have exported them in the CSV file but I'm having trouble with the following. I need the CSV file to have paths in such a way that the part leading up to the `$web` is trimmed out.

For instance if the CSV file is like this:

```
Path
C:\Users\home\facebook website\domain\version\version-feb-2020.txt
C:\Users\home\facebook website\domain\interface\somefile.html
C:\Users\home\facebook android\latest\messenger\messenger app files\code.js
C:\Users\home\facebook android\latest\application\somecode.js
```

I want it to turn out like this:

```
Path
facebook website\domain
\version\version-feb-2020.txt
\interface\somefile.html
facebook android\latest
\messenger\messenger app files\code.js
application\somecode.js
```

I have tried using the following to trim it out:

```
$number = [regex]::matches($fbweb,"\\").count
Select-Object Hash,
        @{
            Name = "FilePath";
            Expression = { [string]::Join("\", ($_.Path -split "\\" | Select-Object -skip ($number)))}
        }
```

Update:
I have tried this:

```
$replace = Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath $web
echo $replace
$RefHash = Import-csv "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fb.csv"
$RefHash | ForEach-Object {
           echo $_.Path
           ($_.Path).Replace($replace, "\")
} | Export-csv "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\replaced.csv"
```

But this just results in the exported csv showing the following:

```
#TYPE System.String
"Length"
"numbers"
"numbers"
"numbers"
```

Comment: I don't see the logic.. Why would `version\version-feb-2020.txt` not have ``domain\`` in front and why is `application\somecode.js` missing ``latest\`` ?

Comment: @Theo Because I just need to write "facebook website" and "facebook app" at the top before their respective files are displayed.

Comment: Yes, I gathered that, but then why does this line `domain\interface\somefile.html` in your desired output have ``domain\``, while this was already in `$web` and why does this line `latest\messenger\messenger app files\code.js` contain ``latest\``, where this is already part of `$app` ??

Comment: I see that was a mistake that I made while typing it here. Please see the changes now.

Comment: Add `-NoTypeInformation` after `Export-csv "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\replaced.csv"`

Comment: It's still displaying information like `System.Collections.Generic.List` and `System.Management.Automation.PSToken`. When I do `echo $replace`, I get: `C:\Users\home\facebook website\domain` which is what I want to replace with just a backward slash (\).

Comment: How can I add a row here in the beginning of each relative path's files?

Comment: On mobile.. will post an answer tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed, you have 2 methods to manage this:

1. Treat the csv file as a text file and do a replace on a get-content:

```
(Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\TestMD5.csv").Replace($replace, "\") | Set-Content "C:\temp\TestMD5updated.csv"
```

2. Import the CSV, separate the each of the parameters, modify what you require and then build a pscustomobject which you then export as csv:

```
#Preparing variables
$scriptdir = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
$sourcecsv = Import-csv -path "C:\temp\TestMD5.csv"
$obj = @()
$root = "C:\Temp"
$web = "Test01\Test02\"
$replace = Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath $web
$target = "\"

#Executing replace
foreach ($line in $sourcecsv) {
    $object = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $algo = $line | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Algorithm'
    $Hash = $line | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Hash'
    $Path = ($line | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Path').Replace($replace, $target)
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Algorithm -Value $algo
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hash -Value $Hash
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $Path
    $obj += $object
    $object
}

$obj | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "$scriptdir\UpdatedVars.csv"
```

The first one is faster, the 2nd one provides you the flexibility that would allow you to build functions that are generalized and modify additional parameters as required.

Answer (score 0):

OK assuming you don't actually need to import and deal with the file as a CSV file.  You simply need to replace the strings in a text file.  If so then you can use get-content instead of import-csv

You want to use [REPLACE](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html).

```
$SourceFile = Get-Content -Path "D:\URL.txt"
$root= "C:\Users\home\"
$web = "facebook website\domain"
$app = "facebook android\latest"
$replace1 = $root+$web
$replace2 = $root+$app

$SourceFile -replace [Regex]::Escape($replace1), "\" -replace [Regex]::Escape($replace2), "\" | Set-Content -Path "D:\urlreplaced.txt"
```

This will do the replace and output the new file to D:\urlreplaced.txt

Comment: I need to do this for all the file paths and I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: If you have an array of the filenames in a variable you can use replace on the array as well.

Comment: I've tried doing that and updated my question with the code as well but it doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: @Scripter9700 see my update.  It doesn't look like you need to read it as a csv just as a text file.

Comment: I do need to read it as a csv as it is then going to be saved somewhere else. I'll try it with this method.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the csv data into a new format as you would like, you could do the following:

```
$root= 'C:\Users\home'
$web = 'facebook website\domain'
$app = 'facebook android\latest'

$webPath = [regex]::Escape((Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath 'facebook website\domain'))
$appPath = [regex]::Escape((Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath 'facebook android\latest'))

$data    = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fb.csv"
$appData = ($data | Where-Object { $_.Path -match "^$appPath" } | Select-Object @{Name = 'Path'; Expression = {$_.Path -replace "^$appPath" }}).Path
$webData = ($data | Where-Object { $_.Path -match "^$webPath" } | Select-Object @{Name = 'Path'; Expression = {$_.Path -replace "^$webPath" }}).Path

# manually create the one-column csv (easiest is to do this in a Here-String)
$newData = @"
Path
$web
$($webData -join [Environment]::NewLine)
$app
$($appData -join [Environment]::NewLine)
"@

# output on screen
$newData

# output to new CSV file
$newData | Set-Content -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\replaced.csv" -Force
```

Output on screen

```
Path
facebook website\domain
\version\version-feb-2020.txt
\interface\somefile.html
facebook android\latest
\messenger\messenger app files\code.js
\application\somecode.js
```